# How to Rename Two Directories of The Same Name Under Github Repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have forked some GitHub Repository which has multiple directories in it:

```
dir_1
dir_2
Dir_1
dir_4
README.md
```

For your info, the dir_1 and Dir_1 have the same name but contain different files. When I tried to clone my forked repo locally, I end up having the following directories with the README file:

```
dir_1
dir_2
dir_4 
README.md
```

What happen is Dir_1 is not there anymore but the only dir_1 is kept. So to resolve this issue I think I need to rename dir_1 and Dir_1 before I clone the forked project locally. For example, dir_1 will remain the same name but Dir_1 will be renamed to dir_1_old. Is this the right approach to fix this? If so, how can I achieve this otherwise what is the better solution for this type of issue?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: is it a public repo by any chance ? can you share the url ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not.

Comment: How did you clone the repo and have a whole directory missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a case insensitive file system (Windows or MacOS), the directories `dir_1` and `Dir_1` are actually "merged" on disk : you should see in your local `dir_1` directory the files of `dir_1` mixed together with the files of `Dir_1`.

Here is a way to rename one of the folders from your case insensitive file system :

```
# start from a clean worktree :
$ git stash

# the following will :
#  * on your disk: move the combined content of Dir_1 and dir_1 to Renamed_1
#  * in git's index: stage the renaming of Dir_1 only
$ git mv Dir_1 Renamed_1

# this will restore the content of dir_1 on your disk :
$ git checkout .
# this will remove the content of dir_1 from Renamed_1 on your disk :
$ git clean -fd Renamed_1

# check your git status : you should see all files from Dir_1/... renamed to Renamed_1/...
$ git status
```

Another way is to rename the folders from a case sensitive file system (e.g : a linux workstation or VM)

---

An illustratiion of how you can land in that situation, and some example commands to inspect what is stored inside git :

Starting from the following situation :

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --all
* ba1a040 (HEAD -> right) created Dir_1 and file_right.txt on branch right
| * 3cb290d (left) created dir_1 and file_left.txt on branch left
|/
* 0d2a900 (master) first commit (README.txt)
```

merging the two branches `left` and `right` will result in :

```
$ git merge left
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 dir_1/file_left.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 dir1/file_left.txt

# in git's storage : there are two distinct directories dir_1 and Dir_1
$ git ls-tree HEAD
040000 tree d6317389dbdebb9fcec7a5f60ba49666bb55cdfb    Dir_1
100644 blob 72943a16fb2c8f38f9dde202b7a70ccc19c52f34    README.txt
040000 tree 9cd36c945344bf39eb3b3fcb642f791f80847dbf    dir_1
$ git ls-tree HEAD:Dir_1
100644 blob 5716ca5987cbf97d6bb54920bea6adde242d87e6    file_right.txt
$ git ls-tree HEAD:dir_1
100644 blob 257cc5642cb1a054f08cc83f2d943e56fd3ebe99    file_left.txt

# when checked out on disk, both directories get "merged"
# (which name wins depends on the order in which the directories were created on disk)
$ ls
README.txt  Dir_1/
$ ls Dir_1/
file_left.txt  file_right.txt
```